# Machine Learning papers for matching packets to request flows

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently doing a research project related to Distributed Tracing. My research has led me to a point where I think ML might be suited for our problem.

I'm looking for papers that are similar to this (even if they have other applications):

I want to match packets exiting a black-box system (outputs) to packets that enter a black box (inputs). I can do that easily in a non concurrent setting which should help  me grow a training set (maybe for supervised learning), but I need an algorithm that, in a concurrent setting, can separate the different request "flows" if you will.

I hope this makes sense.

The closest thing to what I'm looking for is "Aguilera, Marcos K., et al. "Performance debugging for distributed systems of black boxes." ACM SIGOPS Operating Systems Review. Vol. 37. No. 5. ACM, 2003." but it's mostly suited for finding the dependency graph of the system, which I already know.

Thank you